# Facebook showing a warning message for URLs pointing to my webpage

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, warnings

When I share my webpage URLs on Facebook and someone clicks on them he see a warning:

> Sorry, there was a problem with this link:
>   https://www.example.com/en/article_for_something/?v=83&s=fb You
>   can now continue to this website, or go back to the page you were on
>   before. Remember: Only follow links from sources you trust.

These links have worked for years. I started to get this warning last month. Did FB change something?

There are no HTTP redirects and og:url is the same as the shared URL. If I run the URL through Open Graph Object Debugger it shows no errors and no redirects. Everything is fine.

I wonder if FB allows adding URL parameters but it worked before and I couldn't find any restriction on their pages.

Answer (score 0):

Someone solved their similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333271/facebook-link-share-something-went-wrong), they said:

> FB marked one of CDN links as spam or something like that. We changed CDN domains and it worked after cleaning FB cache.

I'm not sure if you have CDN links or not, but if so you might want to look into changing the CDN domains.

Did you use [Facebook's Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)? I am working through a similar issue with my website because my og:image property has to be explicitly provided.