# Facebook link share - Something Went Wrong

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share

I checked probably half of results for this problem, and didn't find out any solution. We have page trainers4me.com, and we have problems with Facebook sharing. If we share link on FB and user with Firefox or Internet Explorer tries to click on link he get a message:

> **Something Went Wrong**
>   Sorry, there was a problem with this link: https://trainers4me.com/ You can now continue to this website, or go
>   back to the page you were on before. Remember: Only follow links from
>   sources you trust.

The problem is that only users with FF and IE gets this error message in Safari and Chrome works just fine.

Well I checked some solutions for this, and all of them are about redirects, CDN. We use www to non-www redirect, cloudfront (CDN), etc.

Checked page with Facebook debugger no errors.

Comment: Hi carli, can you please share a permalink to a post where I can see the problem? I couldn't repro this issue with Firefox. Also please note that Facebook has some automatic anti-spam checks that can ban temporary your link but after confirm that everything is OK, the restriction will disappear. Are you still seeing this warning?

Comment: Hey sorry we already fixed this thing, FB marked one of CDN links as spam or something like that. We changed CDN domains and it worked after cleaning FB cache.